# What causes a Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_report()?

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

I'm trying to instal vBulletin 5 Connect and when trying to access the install.php file i see an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_report() in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/XXX/forum/core/vb/database/mysqli.php on line
>   214

Here is what i run it on:

> MySQL server version: 5.1.68-cll
>
> PHP Version 5.3.25

Any help please?

EDIT:
MySQL is enabled in my php.ini - here is what i see on the phpinfo file:

```
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    1
Client API version  5.1.68
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off
```

Answer (score 10):

The mysql extension is not enabled. If you installed php via package manager you should be able to install a package like `php-mysql`. Name may vary depending on your system.

If you do already have it, you may need to enable the extension in php.ini.

You will have to restart your webserver afterwards.

Comment: I'm not so much of a technical guy I do know couple of things tho.
Can i somehow manage it thru my WHM or do I have to access it somehow else, can I get a reference or a link on how can I do that? Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: If there is a section for PHP settings you may be able to. Otherwise you will have to do this via terminal.

Comment: Can i do it thru `PHP Configuration Editor` in my WHM?

Comment: Just edited my question with the phpinfo information that says i have MySQL enabled.

Comment: or to the majority `php5-mysql`

Answer (score 1):

The *mysql* extension is installed but the error message refers to **mysqli** extension.
The [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) states that

> The mysqli extension is not enabled by default, so the php_mysqli.dll
> DLL must be enabled inside of php.ini.

In your php.ini, uncomment the line :

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and restart your server.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have an idea how to access my php.ini file but I'm rebuilding the apache using EasyApache right now and I've added the MySQL extended (MySQLi), hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the MySQLi PHP extension that is probably NOT enabled on your PHP environment. You have to modify your php.ini to include it:

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

But you have to be sure that it is compiled and installed correctly.